# OpenGL - glGen* and unique identifiers

Tags: opengl

OpenGL defines a few glGen* functions, for example:

```
glGenTextures
glGenFrameBuffers
glGenBuffers
```

Does id generated by glGen function is unique globally or only within a glGen context - for example glGenTextures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object names are only unique within a given space of object names. Usually, that means for the object type itself: texture names, buffer names, etc.

The only exception to this are shader and program objects who share the same name space, and thus their names cannot overlap.